# REgarding Return url in asp .net

Tags: returnurl

pseudocode :

1. declare a variable
2. store Return url in that variable.
3. if variable is not equal to null 
     redirect to returnurl
   else
   redirect to homepage.

can someone give me C# asp .net code for the above mentioned pseudocode as I'm completely new to progamming world???

Comment: you can get it by googling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   string url="http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr" // variable declaration and assigning url to variable 

    if(url !="")           // checking the string variable is empty or not 
  {
Response.Redirect(url);    // variable is not empty redirect to given URL

} 

else

{
Response.Redirect(HOMEPAGE URL);   // else redirect to given home page

}
```

try this and let me now. it will helpful

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. But my returnURl is not static as this "http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr". It varies dynamically. So I have to capture it in a varaible and then validate it.

Comment: can u help me with the code which stores dynamic returnurl..

Comment: @user1942240 Okay how ur getting the url dynamically ... you have to explain a bit more

Comment: My application was developed using C# asp.net and it has 2 modules namely:
Home: http://localhost:57630/Home.aspx?moduleId=1
Store: http://localhost:57630/Store.aspx?moduleId=3

Comment: It is designed in such a way that the user is redirected to home page after login.even if enter http://localhost:57630/Store.aspx?moduleId=2 url in the browser. its redirected to home page after login instead redirecting to store module directly.
the url generated at the time of login is http://localhost:57630/SIPLogin.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSIPStore.aspx%3fmoduleId%3d3&moduleId=3. I want ot capture the returnurl in code level and get redirected to it.

Comment: get the url using session Example Session["url"]="your url" and do the above

Comment: can u plz give that in code format.. because i'm completely new to programming..

Comment: @user1942240 Can you plz kindly post your code .. how your getting the URL